# import external eclipse project into intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I want to import an eclipse project to intellij

I press import project --> external module ---> i would like to press "eclipse"

but I don't have this option.

Where do I download eclipse plugin for intellij ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it in the built-in menu

`Intellij IDEA ---> prefrences ---> plugins --> eclipse integration`